# How to get visual studio 2010 to install a NuGet Package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Solution Template.
When the user creates a solution using this template I want NuGet to get the latest version of that a package and install it.

The package is my own, shared on a network drive, maybe this is the issue.

I've looked at NuGet Restore and the Auto update feature but it still fails to get my package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to how to install packages via Visual Studio Template - http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates.

Currently NuGet supports three package repositories, as discussed by the document. Your template can install a fixed version of NuGet packages; and the template consumer will need to update to the latest version themselves.